# struts tags iterate and select

Tags: select, struts2, iterator

I am trying to build a drop down box in my jsp which has some filenames fetched from DB. I am getting these names as a list into `fileNamesList` which has `elementData` like

I just want to show filenames for example `Default_Campaign`. But instead it shows `FileNames( filename=Default_Campaign`, in the drop down list with the code below in jsp.

```
 <s:select name="emergwav"  list="fileNamesList"
         headerKey="-1" label="emergwav"  
     <s:iterator value="fileNamesList" id="filename">
         <s:property  value="${filename.getEmergwavfilename()}"/>                         
    </s:iterator>       
</s:select>
```

Any help to let me know how to go to the next level of arraylist would be really helpful, I have tried using `s:iterator` in the jsp, but was not successful. I would also like to save the user selected filename into the DB from this drop down list.

Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: You'll need to show your action, or at least what "emergencyNamesList" is because how ever it is being turned into a string isn't nice. In your execute method you'll want to move the content into an ArrayList of String, call that emergencyNamesList and then there won't be any issues.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the action class for your view, any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised, I have not got any replies. I have figured out the solution. I have added a toString method in my bean class to match the output to display just to the level 1.